# Encoding problem in .NET 6 API called from Excel querytable

Tags: c#, excel, api, character-encoding, .net-6.0

I'm porting an old .NET 4 web app to an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

When calling the ASP.NET Core 6 Web API controller using Excel querytable, Danish letters are not shown correctly in Excel.

When the same method is called from the old .NET 4 web app, everything looks fine.

This is the .NET 6 controller that produces the behavior explained above:

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("problem")]
   public async Task Problem()
   {
      Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
      await Response.StartAsync();
      await Response.WriteAsync("abc æøå ÆØÅ");
      await Response.CompleteAsync();
   }
```

In Excel this example will produce "abc Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥ Ã†Ã˜Ã…", but Postman and notepad will show "abc æøå ÆØÅ"...

A comment from @jdweng indicates that the solution might be to change encoding on the output to ANSI (or is it ASCII) - but how is this done in .net6?

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  How are you displaying results?  The encoding on the machine has a different culture and just displaying the characters using a different encoding or using different Font.  After viewing in Notepad from menu File : SaveAs you will see the encoding being used and you can see the Font.  This may give a clue.

Comment: *Danish letters are not shown correctly in Excel*: Do you see `abc µ°Õ ãÏ┼` or `'abc Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥ Ã†Ã˜Ã…` or something else instead of `abc æøå ÆØÅ`? Please [edit] your question to elaborate [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @JosefZ - I have made an edit to clarify how the output looks in Excel

Comment: @jdweng notepad says UTF-8 as I would expect from a .net6 api, but the same output from .net4 webapp says ANSI...

Comment: I'm wondering if issue is the URL issue or a displaying issue (using a different font).  You may be going to a different URL because a HTTP header is different (like language). By converting string to bytes [use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)] and comparing Net 4 with Core 6 will tell if the issue is the connection or the displaying.

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel needs [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to open `utf-8` file correctly. Maybe writing `"\uFEFFabc æøå ÆØÅ"` (at the 1st line only) could help?

Comment: I have tried to follow suggestion from @JosefZ prepending a "Byte order mark" to  the output. Opening the downloaded response from Excel gives the correct output "abc æøå ÆØÅ" - but fetching the response from an Excel querytable outputs "ï»¿abc Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥ Ã†Ã˜Ã… " in the target cell.  But hanks to JosefZ for the advice...